# find maximum with specific data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-order-by

I still confused about sql server, for example i have student table and i try to find maximum mark for java student

```
STUDENT
| id | name  | mark | subject |
|  1 | jenny |  67  |  db    | 
|  2 | mark  |  74  |  java  |
|  3 | nala  |  90  |  java  |
```

i try to get output like this

```
|  3 | nala  |  90  |
```

i write this in sql, but the output is empty.

```
SELECT id,name,mark
FROM student
WHERE subject='Java'
 AND mark=
(SELECT max(mark) FROM student);
```

how i'm supposed to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get what you want in SQL.  However, you should understand the problem with your approach:

```
SELECT id, name, mark
FROM student
WHERE subject = 'Java' AND
      mark = (SELECT max(mark) FROM student);
```

The problem is that the maximum value of `mark` may not be for `'Java'`.  Hence, no rows can pass both `where` conditions.

You need to repeat the filter in the subquery, either explicitly:

```
SELECT id, name, mark
FROM student
WHERE subject = 'Java' AND
      mark = (SELECT max(mark) FROM student WHERE subject = 'Java');
```

Or using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.mark
FROM student s
WHERE s.subject = 'Java' AND
      s.mark = (SELECT max(mark) FROM student s2 WHERE s2.subject = s.subject);
```

Notice that the last query uses table aliases.  You should learn to use these in your queries; sometimes they are necessary and they generally make queries easier to write, read, and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use **TOP 1** with **ORDER BY** clause to fetch highest data

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, name, mark
FROM student
WHERE subject = 'Java'
ORDER BY mark DESC;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT id, name, mark
FROM (SELECT id, name, mark, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mark DESC) AS RowNum
      FROM student
      WHERE subject = 'Java'
     ) AS A 
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use sub query. Use `Top 1 with ties` to get the student with max marks and also  if the max mark is shared by more than one student

`Where condition` will filter the result to have only `subject = 'Java'` after that Top 1 with order by will fetch you the max mark in `java`

```
SELECT TOP 1 with ties id, name, mark
FROM student
WHERE subject = 'Java'
ORDER BY mark DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you are trying (with subquery), you could do:

```
SELECT id,name,mark
FROM student
WHERE subject='Java' 
AND   mark = (SELECT MAX(mark) 
              FROM student 
              WHERE subject='Java');
```

You are trying to fetch max of all the records irrespective of subject name.

Comment: you get a performance hit with this query as the outer query now perform a full table scan for the given mark

Comment: May i know why would it perform full table scan please?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS SIMPLE QUERY TO GET RESULT

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID,NAME,mark FROM STUDENT
  WHERE SUBJECT ='JAVA'
  ORDER BY MARK DESC
```